# Angular2 ViewWrappedError on (component 2) when object deleted from (component 1)

Tags: angular

I'm working on an angular2 application that lets users click-select items from a source list (component1) to a destination list. (component 2) I followed the "astronaut mission" service pattern here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

The service appears to work; when I click an item on the left, it appears on the right. However, when I add code in the click method to delete the item from the source array, I'm getting a ViewWrappedError *regarding the destination list* I'm new to angular so I don't know how to tell if this is a coding or environment/version issue so any tips would be great.

```
onSelect(asset: Asset): void {
   this.buildFundService.selectAsset(asset.id);
    this.universeassets.splice(this.universeassets.indexOf(asset),1);
  }
```

The html for the destination component is:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let asset of assets"
    (click)="onSelect(asset)">
       <span class="badge">{{asset.id}}</span> {{asset.name}}
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Error from browser console is:

```
ViewWrappedError__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./UserFundComponent class UserFundComponent - inline template:4:27 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3322:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26556:16)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26621:16)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58974:16)
    at View_UserFundComponent1.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83726:23)
    at View_UserFundComponent1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83699:18)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83833:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_UserFundComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/UserFundComponent/component.ngfactory.js:188:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83486:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_BuildFundComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/BuildFundComponent/component.ngfactory.js:79:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83486:18)_nativeError: ZoneAwareErrorcontext: DebugContextmessage: (...)name: (...)originalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at View_UserFundComponent1.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/UserFundComponent/component.ngfactory.js:71:71)
    at View_UserFundComponent1.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at View_UserFundComponent1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83833:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_UserFundComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/UserFundComponent/component.ngfactory.js:188:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83486:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_BuildFundComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/BuildFundComponent/component.ngfactory.js:79:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83486:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:49:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83501:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83696:44)originalStack: (...)stack: (...)toSource: ()toString: ()zoneAwareStack: (...)get message: ()set message: (value)get name: ()set name: (value)get originalStack: ()set originalStack: (value)get stack: ()set stack: (value)get zoneAwareStack: ()set zoneAwareStack: (value)__proto__: WrappedError
consoleError @ polyfills.bundle.js:2882
```

And these are the packages I'm using. I tried every version of zone.js from 0.7.2 up (based on some reports that downgrading helped this error) but with no luck.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "buildfund",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside ngFor **assets** variable represents ?

Comment: I should note that the deletion *also* works fine on its own and causes no errors. It's only when I'm attempting to add AND delete that I get an error.

Comment: are you passing the asset from the parent component?

Comment: The two components in question are actually peers. They inject the service provided by app.module.

Comment: you should not use it that way. The problem occurred because components are sharing the data which breaks the app when they become inconsistent

Comment: *ngFor is iterating over the assets: Asset[] array in the component

Comment: They are not sharing data to my knowledge. Each component declares an assets: Asset[] array.

Comment: **this.universeassets.splice(...)** where is this variable comes from?

Answer (score 2):

It is observed that, when you click on that particular **asset**, the record is removed in the child component, which breaks the application. That's the reason you get the above error.

Expected behavior when a delete is clicked, notify the parent about the asset

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let asset of assets"
    (deleteClicked)="onSelect(asset)">
       <span class="badge">{{asset.id}}</span> {{asset.name}}
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Emit the asset to be deleted to the parent component

```
onSelect(asset){
   this.deleteClicked.emit(asset);
}
```

Splice the by handling the emitted event in the parent component.

```
deleteClikced(asset){
     this.buildFundService.selectAsset(asset.id);
     this.universeassets.splice(this.universeassets.indexOf(asset),1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never got to root cause on this, but it was somewhere within a stub service based on the hero service from the the Angular tutorial. Once I setup json-server and updated that hero service to user http.get(url) everything worked.